# Google App Engine logout url

Tags: google-app-engine, logout

I am having problems getting the logout link work in GAE (Python).

This is the [page](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/users/overview.html) I am looking at.

In my template, I create a link

```
<p><a href="\users.create_logout_url("/")\">Logout</a></p>
```

But when I click on it I get "broken link" message from Chrome. The url for the link looks like this:

```
http://localhost:8085/users.create_logout_url(
```

My questions:

Can anybody explain how this works in general?

What is the correct url for the dev server?

What is the correct url for the app server?

What is the ("/") in the logout url?

Thanks.

**EDIT**

This link works; but I don't know why:

```
<p><a href="http://localhost:8085/_ah/login?continue=http%3A//localhost%3A8085/&action=Logout">Logout</a></p>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What sort of templates are you using? It's clear from the output that you're not escaping your code correctly.

Comment: Then you need to do ${users.create_logout_url("/")} to substitute in the result of that expression.

Answer (score 2):

Seems to me that you want to do this instead:

```
self.response.out.write("This is the url: %s", users.create_logout_url("/"))
```

You could also pass it to your template, using GAEs implemented django templates.

```
from google.appengine.ext.webapp import template
...
...
(inside your request handler)
  class Empty: pass
  data = Empty()
  data.logout = users.create_logout_url("/")
  self.response.out.write(template.render(my_tmpl, {'data': data})
```

A useful approach is to add all sorts of info to a BaseRequestHandler and then use this as base class for all of your other request handler classes.

```
from google.appengine.ext import webapp
...
class BaseRequestHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
  def __init__(self):
     webapp.RequestHandler.__init__(self) # extend the base class
     class Empty: pass
     data = Empty()
     data.foo = "bar"
```

Then your new classes will have access to all the data you provided in the base class.

```
class OtherHandler(BaseRequestHandler):
  def get(self):
     self.response.out.write("This is foo: %s" % self.data.foo) # passes str "bar"
```

Hope it helps.

A.

Answer (score 0):

Hi following more or less what this article is showing for the user account stuff. In gwt I store server side the logout/login url and I pass them to the client

http://www.dev-articles.com/article/App-Engine-User-Services-in-JSP-3002